# Sphinx code validation for Django projects

Tags: django, testing, python-sphinx

I have a Django project with a couple of apps - all of them with 100% coverage unit tests. And now I started documenting the whole thing in a new directory using ReST and Sphinx. I create the html files using the normal approach: `make html`.

Since there are a couple of code snippets in these ReST files, I want to make sure that these snippets stay valid over time. So what is a good way to test these ReST files, so I get an error if some API changes made such a snippet invalid? I guess there have to be some changes in conf.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that I had some python paths wrong. Everything works as expected - as noted by bmu in his comment. (I'm writing this answer so I can close the question in a normal way)